# Shell script to print a variable which has delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a shell script, which gets bunch of values. I am segregating it based on a Delimiter(,). Now i want to print it one by one inside a for loop.
For E.g

```
var=/a/b/c,d/e/f/,x/y/z
for i in $(echo $var | sed "s/,/ /g")
do
echo $i
done
```

Output is coming empty, Expected output is

```
/a/b/c
d/e/f/
x/y/z
```

Comment: Works fine for me...

Comment: You can do: `echo "${var//,/$'\n'}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a loop.

```
sed 's/,/\n/g' <<< "$var"
sed 'y/,/\n/' <<< "$var"
tr ',' '\n' <<< "$var"
echo "${var//,/$'\n'}"
```

they all yield the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another option -

```
var="/a/b/c,d/e/f/,x/y/z"
while IFS=, read a b c
do printf "a=$a b=$b c=$c\n"
done <<< "$var"
a=/a/b/c b=d/e/f/ c=x/y/z
```

Doesn't need a loop - works fine as

```
$: IFS=, read a b c <<< "$var"
$: printf "a=$a b=$b c=$c\n"
a=/a/b/c b=d/e/f/ c=x/y/z
```

... just wanted to show the loop structure in case it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could read it into an array. This is quite readable:

```
var=/a/b/c,d/e/f/,x/y/z
IFS=, read -a paths <<<"$var"
for p in "${paths[@]}"; do echo "$p"; done
```

```
/a/b/c
d/e/f/
x/y/z
```